# Linking two docker compose configuration fails with a bridge network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have setup a global docker configuration which i expect to handle nginx,and database configuration. This has the following configuration

```
webserver:
 image: nginx
 container_name: webserver
 restart: unless-stopped
 tty: true
 ports:
 - "80:80"
 - "443:443"
 volumes:
 - ./:/var/www
 - ./dockerconfig/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
 networks:
 - common



networks:
 common:
  driver: bridge
```

on the folder dockerconfig/nginx/conf.d i  have a file pos.test with the following nginx config

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name pos.test www.pos.test;
index index.php index.html;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
root /var/www/web;
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
}
```

}

ON THE SECOND DOCKER configuration file i have
Now i have another docker configuration with the following

```
  app:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
image: posapp/php
container_name: envanto_pos
restart: unless-stopped
tty: true
working_dir: /var/www/pos
volumes:
- ./:/var/www/pos
networks:
- common

networks:
 common:
  driver: bridge
```

Now after running both docker files via `docker-compose up -d` they both run without any issue but now i nginx cannot run the domain `pos.test` where the app code is executed on the second docker file

The idea behind this is to have one docker-compose configuration file handle nginx server while the other configuration to copy files is handled by the other docker configuration files

How can i make both docker configurations work as including the network part with a bridge fails to work.What am i missing out.

UPDATE

I know one of the way to solve this would be to add a single docker config file but i want to split the docker config files to different configuration files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely running the `docker-compose` command from different directories, and not overriding the compose project name. Docker compose will prefix objects created, like containers, volumes, and networks, with the project name, to allow different instances to be run in isolation from each other.

To solve this, you need a known name of the network, and you'll want to define it as external to at least one of your compose files. When the network is defined as external, compose will not try to create it, but will require that it was already created externally, either by a `docker network create` command or by the other compose file.

To create the network with a known name, you can specify the `name` value in newer versions of the docker compose file.

Here is the first compose file that would create the network with a known name:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    webserver:
     image: nginx
     container_name: webserver
     restart: unless-stopped
     tty: true
     ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "443:443"
     volumes:
     - ./:/var/www
     - ./dockerconfig/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
     networks:
     - common



networks:
  common:
    external: false
    name: common
```

And the second compose file that would use the already created network:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: posapp/php
    container_name: envanto_pos
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www/pos
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/pos
    networks:
    - common

networks:
  common:
    external: true
    name: common
```

Comment: Great, what of the volumes will this work with volumes will they be shared across the different containers with the network

Comment: @Geoff The volumes you've defined here are host volumes, bind mounting a directory from the host. They have nothing to do with networking of the containers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're redefining the `common` network.

You can define the 2 docker-compose.yml files as follow:

docker-compose.yml

```
networks:
  common:
    driver: bridge

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: posapp/php
    container_name: envanto_pos
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www/pos
    volumes:
     - ./${AppPath}/:/var/www/pos
    networks:
     - common
```

and docker-compose.webserver.yml

```
services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    volumes:
    - ./${WebserverPath}/:/var/www
    - ./${WebserverPath}/dockerconfig/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
    - common
```

and start the application with:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.webserver.yml up -d
```